# How do I setup the Agora API into Bubble.io?

Tags: api, agora.io

I've downloaded the plugin and set up the account on Agora.io, then linked the account from project management to the interface into Bubble. Once I placed the Agora Connector into the design interface in Bubble and added a few groups and buttons, I have no idea how to set the workflows to get the video conferencing to work.

I've been using the Zeroquode documentation but I have no idea how to get past this point. I tried to copy and pasting the Demo version and editing that but there seem to be problems with my custom states. Any links or documentation would help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen people using Bubble with Agora yet. But Agora released the plugin for WordPress and released the code. Maybe you can check it out to get some ideas?

https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Word-Press